# UILabel - Wrap text so that it is weighted to the bottom left

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, text, uilabel

I'm looking for a way to wrap the text of a `UILabel` (or using another library such as `FXLabel`) so that it is weighted to the bottom left. The labels contain no more than five words.

### **Examples**

*The

Brown Fox*

---

*2017

Top Five

World Events*

---

*The sun

is shining today.*

---

As you can tell, the wrapping is weighed to the bottom left of the label/text box. Any knowledge/ideas of how to do this in `Xcode`/`Objective-C`?

### - Edit -

I am looking for a way to position the line breaks between the words - rather than position the whole label. I do not know enough about fonts/texts to give to correct definition/wording of what I mean - I am sorry.

Comment: Does "weighted" determine where the line break falls in "The sun \n is shining", vs. "The sun is \n shining" ?  If it's just positioning of a normally wrapped label, than @Ramon has a good idea.  If not, then hmmm.  Is there a formal definition of weighting somewhere?

Comment: @danh I'm sorry but I do not know the technical term for it. I am referring to where the line break falls between the word. @Ramon 's answer only positions the   `UILabel` not where the line breaks are in the sentence. So no, I am not looking for his answer.

Comment: Then you must supply a definition of weighted.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to solve this issue is to use a simple auto-sizing `UILabel`, then fix the `UILabel` to the bottom left of it's superview using Auto-layout.

Note: Auto-sizing UILabels are no more than simple UILabels without any width & height constraint set.

Comment: I'm referring to where the line breaks are rather than where the actual `UILabel` is positioned.